# Will my bread dough that has already gone through first rise be okay to bake after three days of refrigeration?

Tags: bread

I was making a loaf of bread in a bread machine on dough setting. This includes the first rise. Removed dough and put into a pan for second rise then bake. My oven died before second rise so I refrigerated the greased and covered dough. It has been three days will it be okay to bake?

Comment: What do you mean by "ok?"

Comment: Bake it and tell us what happens! I bet it will be a bit like sourdough, but that probably depends on the recipe that you used.

Answer (score 1):

From experience... No, it will probably not be 'okay to bake'. It's not going to rise, the yeast will most likely be spent.

Try mixing more dough and incorporate a third of your dough into that as a starter. Then, when that dough is finished mixing, cut a third of it and put it in the fridge for the next time you make bread. Then you've got a heck of a nice starter going.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly fine to eat (food safety wise).
Whether or not it will rise again is open to question, but I think it is likely to be fine: the [no-knead recipe I use](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/no-knead-crusty-white-bread-recipe) does a first rise in warm air, then cold ferment in the fridge, then another rise in warm air before baking and you're not far off that.  It may end up a bit tougher from extra gluten development, but probably nothing awful - I'd love to hear how it goes if you try it.